# How to make Ubuntu 18.04 to auto login into i3

Tags: ubuntu, i3, gdm

I want to have my Ubuntu 18.04.1 system autologin into i3, but all attempts were failures and gdm keeps booting into gnome :(
Things I've tried:

1. I've created `.xinitrc` that launched `i3` (it worked with startx command, but wasn't a default variant for gdm)
2. Made a symlink to `.xsession` `ln -s .xinitrc .xsession`
3. Added `~/.dmrc` file with

   > [Desktop]
   >
   > Session=i3
4. Wrote `DefaultSession=i3` line into `[daemon]` section of `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`
5. I tried doing alternatives with 
   `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-session-manager x-session-manager /usr/share/xsessions/i3.desktop 48`
   and then `update-alternatives --config x-session-manager` with selection of that entry
6. Tried `update-alternatives --config x-window-manager` and set `i3`

None of that helped, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe this can help https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/75k90o/autologin/

Comment: @wdog Thank you for reply, I've tried to use that getty method and it worked. Although it doesn't have that seamless experience of system-level autologin and also if user hits Ctrl+C frequently, he can stop system from booting a DM